# Create custom workflow status values

Tags: workflow, custom, office-365

I am relatively new to Office 365 (SharePoint Online), so bear with me.

How can I create a custom status for my workflow? Say I have the following statuses

- Initiated
- First level approved
- Second level approved
- Finalized

I have looked at some blog posts similar to this - [Setting Workflow Status to Custom Values](http://sharepoint.ginni.me/2010/01/setting-workflow-status-to-custom.html), that say I should be editing `workflow.xml` file. In a cloud hosted Office 365 environment, where can I find the `workflow.xml` and change it?

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your specific question about the workflow.xml, but there is an Action in SPD workflows (the kind that run in O365) that allow you to set the status as you wish:

http://www.schaeflein.net/setting-workflow-status-in-visual-studio-and-sharepoint-designer/